# o3D samples can't run in localhost

Tags: localhost, sample, o3d

I have downloaded the samples from Google o3d,but it can't run in my computer.The question like this:Even I install the o3d plug-in again and again, it always prompt me that I have to install this plug-in when I visit the samples' website that I published in IIS 7.The IE7,opera and chrome has been tested, them are all the same. This is my first time to ask a question using English,so I hope it is clear to you.Thank you for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer,

Find o3d/samples/o3djs/util.js 
and change:

```
o3djs.util.REQUIRED_VERSION = '0.1.42.4';
```

to

```
o3djs.util.REQUIRED_VERSION = '0.1.42.3';
```